# Is "that" being used as a relative pronoun or conjunction in this sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, relative-pronouns

looking for some help on explaining the use of "that" in this sentence. Is it being used a relative pronoun or conjunction in this context?

> There are so many hot springs ***that*** visitors can experience the same types of bath as the ancient Romans enjoyed.

This was a test question and I am confused about which is correct and why. Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Well I am no native speaker and for that I don't actually follow the rules of naming...
but conjunction is like a word _**that**_ merges two separate statements.
but the usage of "that" in that sentence is a relative pronoun I guess... it has the same role of the one I used in this comment signified by italic-bold font

Comment: BTW I double checked and it _**IS**_ a relative pronoun

Comment: @AtrinNoori No: it's not a relative pronoun but a subordinator (subordinating conjunction) introducing the declarative content clause "that visitors can experience the same types of bath as the ancient Romans enjoyed", functioning as complement of "so". It can't be a relative word since it does not refer to a preceding noun, called an antecedent.

Comment: @BillJ Sorry, Whatever the name is in grammatical terminology.. but enlighten me on this one please, "functioning as the complement of "so"."???
you mean this **"there are many hot spring **so** that visitors can enjoy"** ??
I don't actually think that way.. I think "that' plays the role like this...
_"there so many cars **Which** you can choose to drive"_

Comment: @AtrinNoori No: that would be totally wrong. "So many" and "that" are in construction together, i.e. "so many ... that". The content (_that_) clause is licensed by the "so" that modifies "many".

Comment: @BillJ OK. So you mean **there are so many cars that you can choose to drive** is different from **there are so many cars which you can choose to drive**. is that right ?

Comment: @AtrinNoori No: "That visitors can experience the same types of bath as the ancient Romans enjoyed" is the **result** of there being so many hot springs.

Comment: @BillJ Ok. and if we replace _"experience the same types of bath as the ancient Romans enjoyed"_ with _"enjoy"_. does it still mean the same ? I mean instead of _"That visitors can experience the same types of bath as the ancient Romans enjoyed"_, we say _"That visitors can enjoy"_, then the subordinating action is still applied ?

Comment: @AtrinNoori no in that case it's different, it is then a relative pronoun.

Comment: In the structure `"so <adj>/<adv> that" + <clause>`, `<clause>` is the consequence of the quantity of the adjective or adverbial. A clearer example of the structure than in the OP is: `"The restaurant was so empty that each table had their own server."`

That doesn't explain what part of speech "that" is, but it might be enough to say it's part of a set structure

Comment: @BillJ on page 55 of CaGEL it says this type of complement is indirect complement. In our case the NP is - *so many hot springs that visitors can experience the same types of bath as the ancient Romans enjoyed*. And *that visitors can experience the same types of bath as the ancient Romans enjoyed* is a complement in NP structure. But is it licensed by the dependent *so* or *so many*?

Comment: @Man_From_India Yes, the content clause is an indirect complement licensed by "so", as I said in my second-last comment.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "that" is a **[subordinating conjunction](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/subordinating-conjunctions/)**. Subordinating conjunctions link dependent clauses to independent clauses. I'm not sure whether this specifically exists in English, but I recall being introduced to the concept of **result clauses** when learning Latin, some examples of which include:

> He was **so** strong **that** he could lift up the car.
>
> She was **so** old **that** she could barely walk to the kitchen.
>
> They were **so** tired **that** they collapsed before reaching the finish line.

As you can see, *so* and *that* go together in this particular instance. We're expressing the result of a particular event or circumstance.

To address a concern in the comments, if the sentence were

> There are so many hot springs ***where*** visitors can experience the same types of bath as the ancient Romans enjoyed.

you would be dealing with a [*relative pronoun*](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/relative-pronouns-and-relative-clauses) instead. This is because the clause that comes after "where" adds more information about the hot springs themselves. However, in your original sentence, we aren't describing the hot springs in more detail; we're expressing the **result** of having many hot springs in a particular area.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following two sentences:

> **1.** The fact ***that* he is a brilliant student** is not unknown to no one. 
> **2.** I know ***that* he is a brilliant student**,

Here *He is a brilliant student* is a Declarative Content clause, which by itself is independent, but when it is part of a larger constituents [part of a Noun Phrase (NP) in #1 and part of a matrix clause in #2], it becomes subordinate clause. And that *that* just introduces the subordinate clause. The sole purpose of *that* is just that - to introduce a subordinate content clause. We classify it as a **Subordinator**.

In #1 the subordinate clause functions as a Complement of the Noun - *fact*, and in #2 as an internal complement of the Verb - *know*.

Now consider the following sentences -

> **3.** The book ***which* I borrowed from Noelle** is excellent. 
> **4.** The book ***that* I borrowed __ from Noelle** is excellent.

Now *which I borrowed from Noelle* and *that I borrowed from Noelle* are also a subordinate clause but it is different from the ones we saw in #1 and #2. Here they are Relative Clause. It has completely different structure. Even unlike the first set of sentences, it here functions as a modifier in NP structure. It modifies the Nominal - *book* and the whole Noun Phrase is *the book which/that I borrowed from Noelle*. Structurally it is different in that it has an antecedent - here *book*, and which is referred to by the presence of relative pronoun *which* in its Prenuclear Position in case of #3 and is referred to by the presence of a gap in the normal expected position in case of #4. In #4 though *that I borrowed from Noelle* is a relative clause, the *that* here is not a relative pronoun (though Traditional grammar call it that). This *that* here is also a subordinator.

So the important takeaway is that *that* can introduce both a content clause and a relative clause, but it is the presence of gap and antecedent that tells which one is relative clause.

Again note here, *that* is always a subordinator irrespective of whether the clause introduced is a content clause or a relative clause. In traditional grammar *that* in #1 and #2 is a conjunction and in #4 is a relative pronoun.

Back to you sentence:

> There are so many hot springs ***that** visitors can experience the same types of bath as the ancient Romans enjoyed.*

Here in the subordinate clause there is no gap like #4 above or any antecedent like #3 and #4 above. It is not a relative clause; it is a declarative content clause.

In your sentence *that* is a subordinator. Or if I take the terminology of traditional grammar it is a Conjunction and not a relative pronoun.